# Rails 4 selective asset digest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to specify which asset file names get a digest and which are not. Can I do this and how?

I need this functionality because I will use one asset on an external website and this URL needs to be the same.

What is the best solution to this problem?

Comment: AFAIK all assets get a digest

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All files get digested. In Rails 3 all files also had a copy without digest but this was removed in Rails 4. Now you're supposed to have non digested assets in `/public`. A workaround is to create a rake task which copies the assets. More details can be found in https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/49 in there is also a monkey patch to restore the old behavior.

Comment: Another solution is to use this gem: https://github.com/alexspeller/non-stupid-digest-assets